# Need help converting some linux commands to OSX

Tags: linux, macos, iptables, apache-http-server

I want to convert some linux commands into OSX. (Mavericks 10.9.4)

```
root@bt:/# /etc/init.d/apache2 start (will "sudo apachectl start" do the same?)
root@bt:/# echo “some Site Goes Here!” > /var/www/index.html
```

Now I have a site that I host on my macbook local host (8080). So would `echo localhost:8080 > /var/www/index.html` do the same as above in OSX ?

---

Next set of cammands I have no idea how to replace in OSX. Please help

```
root@bt:/# iptables -t nat --flush
root@bt:/# iptables --zero
root@bt:/# iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface eth0 -j ACCEPT
root@bt:/# iptables -t nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
# Forward to our site
root@bt:/# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 --jump DNAT --to-destination <Proxy’s IP>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Apache

### Service

Manual start/stop: `sudo apachectl start` and `sudo apachectl stop`

System autostart: `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`

### Root directory

The default directory used by Apache is set to `/Library/WebServer/Documents`

So you can run `echo "some Site Goes Here!" > /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html`

I would recommend you to change the default settings to suit your needs, the default config is in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.

## Firewall

You want to force NAT and redirection of port TCP/80. Mavericks use Packet Filter (PF) firewall from OpenBSD, ported from FreeBSD.

`echo "nat from !(en0) -> en0
rdr on en0 from !(en0) inet proto tcp to port 80 -> PROXY-IP" | pfctl -f -`

Disable NAT e redirections: `pfctl -F nat`

Comment: thanks a lot for clearing up the Apache stuff. I am still a bit confused with the `iptable` stuff. Would you mind walking me though the commands i posted in the question and tell me exactly what they are doing? And what is your command doing ?

Comment: The command that I've stated simply redirects all HTTP connections to localhost, nothing else, but I don't know if that's exactly what are you looking for. If possible, describe what you need with those iptables commands.

Comment: ok so I am following this tutorial here http://www.arppoisoning.com/demonstrating-an-arp-poisoning-attack/ . I have managed to get everything working uptill step 5 in that tutorial.

PS - how do i reverse your redirection command later on ?

Comment: I see, in this case you will really need the redirection. I'll update it there.

Comment: would this redirection be different from the one you posted?

Comment: Just updated the firewall rules.

Comment: You are a legend dude. Just a few follow up questions: 1> should i disable the NAT redirections first and then run the firewall commands? 2> should the `PROXY-IP` in the second command be replaced with `192.168.0.18:8080` (ip of my macbook hosting the site) ?

Comment: If it's running in the same box you can change "PROXY-IP" to "127.0.0.1 port 8080", if another box, "192.168.0.18 port 8080". The command "-F nat" will flush all NAT and redirections rules. There are few apps to manage Mavericks native firewall: [IceFloor](http://www.hanynet.com/icefloor) and [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/). You can get more info on http://www.hanynet.com/icefloor/
http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/05/15/using-pf-on-os-x-mountain-lion/

Comment: could you please check the quotation marks in thr Firewall part of your answer. Seems like you are missing some. Also `echo "nat from !(en1) -> en1` gives me the error : `-bash: !: event not found`

Comment: Change the double quotes to single quotes or escape exclamation sign with backslash (`\!`)